# _casterror (null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have the follwing problem with my code. When I call a Int with SharedPreference then show the emulator the error "_casterror (null check operator used on a null value)". The error is showing only when I start the app.When starting, the value should be _pktH = 0.

```
...    
int? _pktH;
...
     void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _loadCounterH();
}
 

_loadCounterH() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        setState(() {
          _counterH = (prefs.getInt('counterH') ?? 1);
          prefs.setInt('counterH', _counterH!);
          _pktH = (prefs.getInt('pktH') ?? 0);
          prefs.setInt('pktH', _pktH!);
          print(Text("Save number is: $_counterH"));
          print(Text("Save pkt is: $_pktH"));
        });
      }



 String _abzeichenH;

    if (_pktH! >= 2835) {
      _abzeichenH = ' ' + ' \u{1F451}' + ' ' + 'Ingenieur/-in';
    } else if (_pktH! >= 1890) {
      _abzeichenH = ' ' + '\u2692' + '\u2692' + '\u2692' + ' ' + 'Arbeiter/-in';
    } else if (_pktH! >= 1260) {
      _abzeichenH = ' ' + '\u2692' + '\u2692' + ' ' + 'Azubi';
    } else if (_pktH! >= 10) {
      _abzeichenH = ' ' + '\u2692' + ' ' + 'Praktikant/-in';
    } else {
      _abzeichenH = '';
    }
    print('Dein Abzeichen ist $_abzeichenH');
```

[image]

Comment: Is `_pktH` having value before read time? Can you find value for it on debugging?

Comment: Yes I load `_loadCounterH` with: 
`void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounterH();´
as a result, ´_pktH´ should become ´0´ if it has the value ´null´.

Comment: The thing I can assume(because cant see full snippet) here,  ` _loadCounterH() async` is on loading mode and `_pktH` is using reading it value and getting null.

Comment: `_loadCounterH` is asynchronous.  You are not guaranteeing that whatever code does `if (_pktH! >= 2835) {` runs after `_loadCounterH` completes.

Comment: Thank you @jamesdlin but how do I solve my Problem?

Comment: You haven't shown the code that calls Ensure that whatever code calls `_loadCounterH`.  You should make the caller use `await` to wait for it to complete.  If you have code that might run before it completes, then that code *cannot* use `_pktH!` and must check whether it's `null` first.

Comment: Thanks. I have edit my question. I call `__loadCounterH` with `initState()`. How I use  `await` in ` initState()`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't.  Use a `FutureBuilder`.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/